# Definition with roman counter value

Tags: macros, counters, roman-numerals

Is it possible to write a definition with a counter value?

I have many definitions with a Roman numeral:

```
\def\abcI{} ..
\def\abcII{} ..
\def\abcIII{} ..
```

But this is not possible:

```
\newcounter{myabc}
\addtocounter{myabc}{1}

\abc\Roman{myabc}
\stepcounter{myabc}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
\newcommand*\abcRoman[1]{\csname abc\Roman{#1}\endcsname}

...

\abcRoman{myabc}
\stepcounter{myabc}
```

Well, I suspect that this may not be what you really need, however, that depends on [knowing what you want to use your code for](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).

---

As egreg suggests, if you can use lowercase roman numerals for your macros, you can get on the safer side:

```
\newcommand\abci{...}
\newcommand\abcii{...}
\newcommand\abciii{...}
\newcommand*\abcroman[1]{\csname abc\romannumeral\value{#1}\endcsname}

...

\newcounter{myabc}
\setcounter{myabc}{1}

\abcroman{myabc}
\stepcounter{myabc}
```

Comment: While `\Roman` is safe in ordinary conditions, it may give wrong results (aka puzzling errors) when certain `babel` languages are loaded.

Comment: What do you suggest -- `\rommannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname`? (Damn, I can't even test things now, I'm on Windoze `:(` )

Comment: If one wants to be on the safe side, it's better to use lowercase Roman numerals and `\romannumeral` (but after `\csname`, of course. `\csname abc\romannumeral\value{#1}\endcsname` would do, preserving expandability.